# Java Mission Control (Flight Recorder) Memory/Live Objects view blank for remote JVMs

Tags: java, java-mission-control

Using Java Mission Control 7 from OpenJDK 11. When I make a Flight Recording of a JVM running on my local PC I get data in the Live Objects tab

However when I run the same settings against a remote JVM I get allocation stack traces but the Live Objects tab is always blank (there is no gc root information). The remote VMs are also Java 11.

Does Live Objects capture work for remote VMs? Do I need to enable anything on those remote VMs that would not be enabled by default?